# Stop and start setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to stop a loop so other things can run, then return to the loop again at the correct time in the sequence. The code I have runs once, but then seems to be unable to run after I use `clearInterval();`

```
function runPlanner() {

    var plannerInterval = setInterval(function(){

        imageCounter++;

        var imageTotal = $('li img').length;

        if (imageCounter > imageTotal + 1) {
            $('li img').hide();
            imageCounter = 0;
            clearInterval(plannerInterval);
        } else {
            $('li img:nth-child(' + imageCounter +')').fadeIn('slow');
        }

        console.log('image counter:',imageCounter);
        console.log('image total:',imageTotal);
    }, 2500);

}
```

Then I can run this initially, with:

```
runPlanner();
```

But if the condition is met, where clearInterval is called, then using that function call doesn't work. Any ideas, please!?

Comment: so, `runPlanner();` doesnt work when you call it again

Comment: @okuznetsov What is `imageCounter = 0;` if not resetting it?

Comment: it is better to reset the counter before the setinterval. Not in the condition.

Comment: `imageCounter` looks like global variable

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `setTimeout` style. so you will not have a problem with `clearInterval` anymore.

like this.

```
function runPlanner() {

        imageCounter++;

        var imageTotal = $('li img').length;

        if (imageCounter > imageTotal + 1) {
            $('li img').hide();
            imageCounter = 0;
        } else {
            $('li img:nth-child(' + imageCounter +')').fadeIn('slow');

            // re-called `runPlanner` after 2500 sec
            setTimeout(runPlanner, 2500);
        }

        console.log('image counter:',imageCounter);
        console.log('image total:',imageTotal);

}

runPlanner();
```

Comment: I've just realised, it is because I am using an index variable and an nth child variable. index starts at 0, nth child starts at 1! That'll learn me!